# Configuring tooltips for Flot charts where data is from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flot

I have a series of charts on a page which all get their data from an ajax call. I'm trying to implement the tooltips plugin. I have set grid{ hoverable: true} but I'm still not getting any tooltips.

Code for one of my chart plots...

```
$(function() {
    var data = [];

    getData();

    function getData() {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $.ajax({
            url:'data/prod.php',
            dataType:'json',
            success:update,
            error: function(){
            }
        });
    }

    function update(ajaxdata) {
        if(ajaxdata){
            $.each(ajaxdata, function(key, value){
                data.push(value);
            });

            if(data.length>0){
                $.plot('#graph-1', [data], {
                    series: {color:"#009390",
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.5,
                        fill: 0.7,
                        align: "center"
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true
                    },
                    tooltip: { //corrected from tooltips to tooltip but issue remains
                        show: true,
                        content: "$s: $x - $y"
                    },
                    legend:{
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "categories",
                    tickLength: 0,
                    axisLabel: 'Product Categories',
                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
                    axisLabelColour: '#333',
                    axisLabelPadding: 10
                },
                yaxis:{
                    axisLabel: 'Number of Products',
                    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 15,
                    axisLabelColour: '#333',
                    axisLabelPadding: 10
                }
            });

            $('#graph-1').css('background','#fff');
            data = [];
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen some examples that bind to the plothover event but I'm not sure how to implement this into the code above where the plotting is initiated from an ajax call.

Comment: Do you use the [tooltip plugin](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip)? Then you must use `tooltip` not `tooltips` in the options.

Comment: @Raidri  - Yes I'm using the tooltip plugin. Thanks for spotting typo... have corrected but still have the same issue. No tooltip showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues:

1) Options for the tooltip plugin belong under `tooltip` not `tooltips` (already fixed in question).

2) Both `grid` and `tooltip` options don't belong under the `series` options but beside them.

3) Inside the `content` format string variables are marked by `%` not `$`.

Fixing all these leads to working tooltips: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/706ag8m0/)

Comment: Sorry for delay in accepting you answer... Many thanks